# change password code error

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a code to change a password. Now it seem contain an error. When I fill in the form to change password, and click save the error message:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\e-Complaint(FYP)\userChangePass.php on line 103
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\e-Complaint(FYP)\userChangePass.php on line 103

I really don’t know what the error message means. Please guys. Help me fix it.

Here's is the code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php # change password.php

//set the page title and include the html header.
$page_title = 'Change Your Password';
//include('templates/header.inc');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//handle the form
    require_once('connectioncomplaint.php');//connect to the db.
    //include "connectioncomplaint.php";

    //create a function for escaping the data.
    function escape_data($data){
        global $dbc;//need the connection.
        if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')){
            $data=stripslashes($data);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($data, $dbc);
    }//end function

    $message=NULL;//create the empty new variable.

    //check for a username
    if(empty($_POST['userid'])){
        $u=FALSE;
        $message .='<p> You forgot enter your userid!</p>';
    }else{
        $u=escape_data($_POST['userid']);
    }

    //check for existing password
    if(empty($_POST['password'])){
        $p=FALSE;
        $message .='<p>You forgot to enter your existing password!</p>';
    }else{
        $p=escape_data($_POST['password']);
    }

    //check for a password and match againts the comfirmed password.
    if(empty($_POST['password1'])) {
        $np=FALSE;
        $message .='<p> you forgot to enter your new password!</p>';
    }else{
        if($_POST['password1'] == $_POST['password2']){
        $np=escape_data($_POST['password1']);
    }else{
        $np=FALSE;
        $message .='<p> your new password did not match the confirmed new password!</p>';
    }
}

if($u && $p && $np){//if everything's ok.

    $query="SELECT userid FROM access WHERE (userid='$u' AND password=PASSWORD('$p'))";
    $result=@mysql_query($query);
    $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num == 1){
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);

        //make the query
        $query="UPDATE access SET password=PASSWORD('$np') WHERE userid=$row[0]";
        $result=@mysql_query($query);//run the query.
        if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {//if it run ok.

            //send an email,if desired.
            echo '<p><b>your password has been changed.</b></p>';
            include('templates/footer.inc');//include the HTML footer.
            exit();//quit the script.

        }else{//if it did not run OK.
            $message= '<p>Your password could not be change due to a system error.We apolpgize for any inconvenience.</p><p>' .mysql_error() .'</p>';
            }
        }else{
            $message= '<p> Your username and password do not match our records.</p>';
        }
        mysql_close();//close the database connection.

    }else{
        $message .='<p>Please try again.</p>';
    }
}//end oh=f the submit conditional.

//print the error message if there is one.
if(isset($message)){
    echo'<font color="red">' , $message, '</font>';
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">





<body>
<script language="JavaScript1.2">mmLoadMenus();</script>
<table width="604" height="599" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="130" colspan="7"><img src="images/banner(E-Complaint)-.jpg" width="759" height="130" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100" height="30" bgcolor="#ABD519"></td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#ABD519"></td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#ABD519"></td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#ABD519"></td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#ABD519"></td>
    <td width="160" bgcolor="#ABD519">
    <?php include "header.php"; ?>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<fieldset><legend> Enter your information in the form below:</legend>

<p><b>User ID:</b> <input type="text" name="username" size="10" maxlength="20" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['userid'])) echo $_POST['userid']; ?>" /></p>

<p><b>Current Password:</b> <input type="password" name="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /></p>

<p><b>New Password:</b> <input type="password" name="password1" size="20" maxlength="20" /></p>

<p><b>Confirm New Password:</b> <input type="password" name="password2" size="20" maxlength="20" /></p>
</fieldset>

<div align="center"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change My Password" /></div>

</form><!--End Form-->

    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's line 103 in the file "C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\e-Complaint(FYP)\userChangePass.php" ?

Comment: There is only one mention of `mysql_real_escape_string` in the code. It's not that hard to figure out which line is 103rd.

Comment: Nevertheless for all we know this _could_ be the wrong part of the file or the completely wrong file altogether ;-) Isn't that always the suspicion if a heap of code -some maybe related some obviously unrelated- is thrown at you?

Comment: @Pentium10: Only one mention that's located in line 18, not 103...

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return mysql_real_escape_string($data, $dbc);
```

to

```
return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
```

Your $dbc is not a resource, it was null.

Comment: This might work if there is only one database connection. But if you pass no connection resource to mysql\_real\_escape\_string() and there is no active database connection (not only that it was assigned to another variable but _no_ connection has been made at all) it will try to establish the default connection ...which is usually not what you want. Therefore I would advice against removing the second parameter. `global $dbc` isn't perfect either though....

Comment: @VolkerK How many scripts that uses more than one connection you've ever seen?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Let me throw the ball back into your court: "You haven't?" ;-) It really doesn't matter as it is not the point I wanted to make. The default connection thingy was. But e.g. phpmyadmin seems to use multiple database connections when doing data synchronization between servers.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: At least two of the PHP based applications I develop may at any given time have multiple database connections open. It's good practice to always store the db link in a variable and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one occurrence of mysql_real_escape_string() and it relies on the global variable $dbc to be set to the mysql connection resource try.

```
function escape_data($data){
  global $dbc;//need the connection.
  if ( !is_resource($dbc) ) {
    die('database connection resource not initialized');
  }

  if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')){
    $data=stripslashes($data);
  }

  return mysql_real_escape_string($data, $dbc);
}
```